# I have a control on my form I cant reference from code

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Listbox "Termékek", and it isn't shown in the "Windows Form Designer generated code", like for example:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox Rendelések;
```

I want to store data to an array:

```
string[] lines = { Termékek.SelectedItems.toString(), dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString(), numericUpDown1.Value.ToString() };
```

and it shows the error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0103  The name 'Termékek' does not exist in the current context   POLCZ   C:\...\Form1.cs    86  N/A

Edit: I do have a Listbox named "Termékek", and it has a function, and that's working

```
public void Termékek_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
dateTimePicker1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: All we can tell you is we probably agree with the error message.  You don't have a ListBox with that name on your form.

Comment: But I do have a Listbox with that name

Comment: Look at your post.  How can we help you determine that?

Comment: Sorry, changed the post

Comment: That's just a method name.  Did you use to have a ListBox with that name on the form?  Did you set `GenerateMember` to false?

Comment: I'm not sure what `GenerateMember` does, but it's on false.

Comment: The default is true.  Turn it back on.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem ^^

Comment: Maybe someone should answer this for completeness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had the `GenerateMember` property set to false.  The default is true.

From [How to: Use the Modifiers and GenerateMember Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-the-modifiers-and-generatemember-properties?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

> The GenerateMember property specifies when the Windows Forms Designer generates a member variable for a component.

It's typically used on labels and such where your code would never interact with that control.